# When to report errors during beta testing

Tags: bug-reporting, testing, beta

I have an amateur question. I've noticed with the 18.04 beta (budgie-flavor) that usually when I have a bug, it's usually fixed with another update. Most of my bugs seemed to be an issue with a delay between support packages and supported packages being fixed/uploaded. So my question, how long should I wait before I report a bug that pops up after an update that does not automatically prompt apport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Report bugs right away because that's what beta releases are for. If nobody reports the bugs in a beta release then they'll never get fixed, and these bugs may eventually be passed on unreported to a supported release and in the case of Ubuntu 18.04 to a supported LTS release. Because of this Ubuntu waits until the first point release of a new LTS before it tells users of the old one about it in order to upgrade to the new LTS release.